# TinyMCE remove <script> tags from entire HTML including <head>

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Is there a way to make tinyMCE delete all script tags, no matter where they are in the html document?

Adding `invalid_elements : 'script',` to the tinyMCE correctly removes `<script>` tags from the `<body>` of the html document, but not the `<head>`.

Context: This tinyMCE is creating an email, so no JS should be present.

Code:

```
tinymce.init({
            menubar : false,
            branding: false,
            selector: "textarea#email_wysiwyg1",
            theme: "modern",
            width: '755',
            height: '500',
            convert_urls: false,
            plugins: [
                "advlist autolink link image lists charmap preview hr anchor pagebreake fullpage"
            ],
            custom_elements: '~center',
            invalid_elements : 'script',
            extended_valid_elements: '',
            fontsize_formats: "10px 12px 14px 16px 18px 24px 30px 36px",
            toolbar: "code | bold italic underline hr forecolor backcolor | link unlink | undo redo | 
            bullist numlist | outdent indent | alignleft aligncenter | alignright alignjustify | image preview |"

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The settings for TinyMCE will generally apply to the body of the content.  I see you are using the `fullpage` plugin.  Is there a specific reason you are using that?  Do you want the content creator to manipulate the `<head>` of the content in TinyMCE?  Are you saving that somewhere?

We have quite a few customers using TinyMCE to make emails but I would tell you it is rather rare to allow access to the `<head>` of the content while in TinyMCE.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In this case, using the fullpage plugin was the incorrect design decision (not mine). I will refactor the system so that it doesn't use it.